# Replace for a pattern

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I tried replacing the pattern of `==` with `.equals(`. But for closing the bracket `)` , I am facing an issue as each time the pattern might be different. So what should I consider as the base criteria?

For the below code the pattern I wrote works fine but when the pattern changes for example if the message is as : `if ((var1 == null) || (var1.equals(""))) { var1 = "id";}`, then my code fails.

```
message = '''if (var1 != null && var1 == "") var1 = null;'''

message = message.replace('==','.equals(')
result = re.sub('\&\&(.+?)\)', '\\1))', message)
```

I want a pattern that can modify `==` as `.equals()` without disturbing the variables and existing code.

Comment: This isn't something a regular expression is suited to. Determining what the second operand to `==` is isn't straightforward and depends on things like operator precedence that you can't represent in regex.

Comment: @jonrsharpe : So we might not get a straightforward pattern ??

Comment: Not so much *"might not"*, as *"definitely won't, if it's even possible"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for something that will work 100% of the time, then you need a language parser.

However, if I'm correct that you're just trying to do a find/replace over a large body of code, so something more like 80% would be acceptable (and you can fix anything that goes wrong), then something like the following should suit your needs:

```regex
([a-zA-Z]\w+|[)])(\s*==\s*("[^"]*"|\w+)(?=\s*[|;&)]))
```

You can use group references in your replace string to get the contents of your groups, which will allow you to preserve the matched stuff. Like this:

```
$1.equals($3)
```

This will convert some code like this:

```
if ( foo == "bar" || foo == baz && foo == baz + 1 /*right hand side too complex*/ && bar == baz ){

  foo = baz( "bat" ) == bar;
  foo = bar == baz( "bat" ); // right hand side is too complex
  bar = 77 == 99; // left hand side is not a variable
  bar = bat == 99;
  bar = bat == 99.0; // floats not supported

}
```

Into this:

```
if ( foo.equals("bar") || foo.equals(baz) && foo == baz + 1 /*right hand side too complex*/ && bar.equals(baz) ){

  foo = baz( "bat" ).equals(bar);
  foo = bar == baz( "bat" ); // right hand side is too complex
  bar = 77 == 99; // left hand side is not a variable
  bar = bat.equals(99);
  bar = bat == 99.0; // floats not supported

}
```

Here's a demo: https://regexr.com/461lm

Note that this does not attempt to do more complex replaces where the right hand side of the `==` is an expression, but it will handle simple variables and strings and integers.

Answer (score 0):

Well, for now I approached it by writing a pretty simple function, but of course I'd want to see what longer code you'd need to assure this works correctly. Everything I tested this against works. By the way I combined ""regex" and "replace" because replace is awesome

**Input**

```
>>> def replace_equals(message):
        import re
        found_equals = list(set(re.findall('[\s]+==[\S\s]*?\)', message)))
        for i in range(len(found_equals)):
            edit_found_equals = found_equals[i].replace(' == ', '.equals(').replace(')', '))')
            message = message.replace(found_equals[i], edit_found_equals)
        print(message)
```

**Output**

```
1.
>>> message = '''if (var1 != null && var1 == "") var1 = null;'''
>>> replace_equals(message)
'if (var1 != null && var1.equals("")) var1 = null;'

2.
>>> message = '''if ((var1 == null) || (var1.equals(""))) { var1 = "id";}'''
>>> replace_equals(message)
'if ((var1.equals(null)) || (var1.equals(""))) { var1 = "id";}'
```

**Basic Explanation**

I use regex (re.findall) to find every occurrence of " ==[any amount of characters and terminate when you hit a ')']" and place them in a list. I the iterate over that list, edit the string that I've found to replace " == " with ".equals(" and ")" with "))" then search the message for the original string I found and replace that with the new edit of that string I created.

Comment: Thanks, yes your solution works fine for this particular pattern but doesnt work as a generalised pattern.

Comment: Yea, I figured as much. I see the other answer has your approval which is great though.

Comment: Yeah that answer gave me an idea to solve 50 % of my problem :) using various if clauses.